# CSS :nth-of-type() and :not() selector?

Tags: css, css-float, css-selectors

I have floated articles side by side that are 25% wide. I'm adding a `clear:both` after every fourth element. However I need to insert a graphical section-break inbetween the elements. And it has to be inside the `<ul>`. To be valid I wrapped the "section-break" (the first li item in the sample underneath) into a `<li>` as well.

```
<ul>
    <li class="year"><h1>THIS IS A SECTION Break and 100% wide</h1></li>
    <li>This is a article and only 25% wide</li>
    <li>This is a article and only 25% wide</li>
    <li>This is a article and only 25% wide</li>
    <li>This is a article and only 25% wide</li>
</ul>
```

I want every fourth element to be a line break so I use …

```
ul li:nth-of-type(4n+1) { clear: both; }
```

However I want the `li.year` not to be affected by this behaviour so I tried this

```
ul li:not(.year):nth-of-type(4n+1) { clear: both; }
```

Right now the last `<li>` in my sample code above is floated into the next line but that shouldn't happen since the first `<li>` isn't one of the floated articles but contains a headline.

Is it possible to stack the `:not` and `nth-of-type()` selector onto each other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The selector you have --

```
ul li:not(.year):nth-of-type(4n+1) { background: yellow; }
```

-- is perfectly correct ([as shown by highlighting the selector](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ycu9/)).

<s>The issue is with how you're using `clear`.  It works if you use `clear:right`, and then `clear:left` on the following element:</s>

```
ul li:not(.year):nth-of-type(4n+1) { clear: right;  }
ul li:not(.year):nth-of-type(4n+2) { clear: left;  }
```

**Edit per comments**  The stricken-out text is nonsense.  The real issue, as per BoltClock's answer, is that the `:not` pseudo-class doesn't affect `nth-of-type`.  Adjusting the selector offset works in this case by coincidence, but would not work if the `:not` pattern was different.

```
ul li:not(.year):nth-of-type(4n+2) { clear: left;  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8MuCU/

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly — even thought I don't get it. Any explanation on that?

Comment: @matt honestly, I have no idea.  Stared at the MDN doc for like 5 minutes, and I'm still confused.  It makes no sense.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/clear

Comment: Actually, the issue seems to be in the selector instead. Notice that you're applying `clear: left` to `:nth-of-type(4n+2)` as opposed to `:nth-of-type(4n+1)` in the original; your `clear: right` on the original selector has no effect because none of the elements are being floated to the right.

Comment: @BoltClock you're right, the `clear:right` CSS has no effect: http://jsfiddle.net/8MuCU/1/.  And yet, the :not selector *does* work: http://jsfiddle.net/8MuCU/2/.  I think the issue is that the *:not* pseudo-class doesn't affect the nth-of-type calculation.

Comment: @dbaseman: That's what I pointed out in my original answer. Looks like we all had each other confused ;)

Comment: @matt consider accepting BoltClock's answer, as it's the correct one ... mine is of the "stopped clock is right twice a day" variety.

Answer (score 9):

The reason your `:not()` doesn't appear to work is because the `li.year` is of the same element type as the rest of your `li` elements (naturally), so `:nth-of-type(4n+1)` matches the same elements regardless of the `.year` class.

It's not possible to stack selectors sequentially either. That's just not how they work.

Since you can't change your `li` elements to something else because of HTML markup rules, and `:nth-match()` is in a [future spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4) and hasn't been implemented yet, you have to make do with changing your `:nth-of-type()` formula to accommodate the structure instead:

```
ul li:not(.year):nth-of-type(4n+2) { clear: both; }
```