# Complicated nth-of-type selector with :not() and uneven count of objects? clearing every fourth element

Tags: css, css-float, css-selectors

I really need your help with this because I've no idea if this is even possible or correct.

**This is my HTML**

[image]

So, as you can see I have a `<ul>` with multiple `<li>`'s in it. And what makes my whole thing complicated is the fact that there are `<li class="wrapper year">` in it.

All those `<li>`'s are floated side by side in 4 columns. I need a `clear` after every 4th element so the next row is horizonatally on the same level. However the `<li class="wrapper year">` items are excluded from this behaviour because they should always `clear:both`.

First off, I know this might not be the perfect HTML Structure to have the "year" count also in a `<li>` element but based on the CMS in the backgound it might not be possible to do this in another way!

**This is the CSS**

```
ul.event-items li:not(.year):nth-of-type(4n+1) { clear: right; }
ul.event-items li:not(.year):nth-of-type(4n+2) { clear: left; }
```

**[Here is a live demo of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/wQTBh/4/)**

This almost works fine, however I don't get why the following is happening?!

So, as you can see the year 2012 as a count of 11 items, 2011 has 13 items, and 2010 has 12 items. So the vary because those items are based on a CMS.

The floating and clearing (after every 4th `li`) seems to work fine for 2012 and 2011 but when it comes to 2010 you can see the there is a clear after the 2nd element in this row. Why is that?

Comment: Instead of posting a huge image, post a live demo of the problematic code in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wQTBh/

Comment: It could just be me, but your demo is just random black blocks and doesn't look like the image you posted here. Is the CSS the same?

Comment: @Blender add 1px margin to all `li`s and you'll see

Comment: @matt: The problem is the HTML structure. Wrap every chunk of boxes along with its respective header element inside of a wrapper and your CSS should be much easier to work with.

Comment: Your `clear:right;` makes absolutely no sense - and it's just coincidence that it works with your `4n+1`...

Comment: @Blender That is the problem. I know that this would be much easier, but it's almost not possible with the CSS I'm working with … Here is the updaed fiddle with 1px margin … http://jsfiddle.net/wQTBh/4/

Comment: The same weird problem is if I only have two items in the `ul` I want them of course side by side because 4 would fit in a row – http://jsfiddle.net/wQTBh/6/

Comment: Have you seen my answer to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356158/css-nth-of-type-and-not-selector) and the comments on the accepted answer? Like @Christoph said, the `clear: right` doesn't actually do anything here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because of your selector:

```
ul.event-items li:not(.year):nth-of-type(4n+2) { clear: left; }
```

You've an "orphan" in 2011. So the third li in 2010 is actually targeted by the rule above.
What you can do is to add two "blank" `li`s at the end of 2011.

Check the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/F8x8t/) (the yellow ones are "blanks"). You can hide them if you want (same background color as the container etc.)

Over time, i'm sure, this structure will give you a lot of trouble. If you can't divide it in many `ul`s, at least use some other classes and markers...

Instead of targeting clearing `li`s with nth-of-type, add them a class (eg. *clear-left*, you actually don't neet the `clear:right;`). The html will be a little "heavier", but it's surely safer.

Check this **[updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/FnuXx/)** for another way to do it without `nth-of-type` and `clear:right;`

---

If you want to add the clear-left dynamically with jQuery, [check this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/FnuXx/).

Here's the function i used:

```
$('li.year').each(function(){
    $(this).nextAll('li').each(function(i){
        var li = $(this);
        /* break the loop when a new year is found */
        if(li.hasClass('year')) return false; 
        /* add clear-left to each 5th element */
        if( i > 0 && i % 4 == 0 ) li.addClass('clear-left');                      
    });
});​
```

Comment: the selector you mention actually has absolutely nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Christoph can you use chrome developers tools or bugzilla? check it.

Comment: The issue with the selector was also covered in his previous question which I've addressed in a comment.

Comment: @BoltClock ok, i got what you mean.

Comment: Any idea how too loop over this elements with jQuery and add this `.clear-left` class?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this markup is not suited for your data.
The result you are trying to achieve clearly one of 2 different approaches to markup.

1. Create nested unordered lists

   [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wQTBh/29/)
2. Create a table
   Clearly every year needs a separate table with a TH and a title and multiple rows whith 4 columns in it.

Do not shy away from using tables to represent tabular data. If you are 100% sure your data is not tabular, but listed, give the list an additional depth to better represent your data.